# Are instructions after a return statement pointless?

Tags: php

From what I understand, when you hit a `return` instruction, the subroutine ends and returns back to the main program. So, is anything after a return statement useless?

eg.

```
switch ($foo) {
    case 'one':
        return true;
        break;
    case 'two':
        return true;
        break;
    default:
        header('Location: / ');
        die();
        break;
}
```

Are the `break`'s useless? How about the `break` after `die()`?

eg2.

```
function foo($bar)
{
    if($bar != 1)
    {
        return false;
        die();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is the `die()` here useless as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need `break` in `default` case.And Yes after `return` everything is useless.It wont take them to execute the other after the `return`

Comment: Edit: after return everything before next `case` or `default` keyword is useless

Answer (score 0):

everything after return in code block is dead code (unreachable statements). You can use IDE like PhpStorm it signalize unreachable statements.

Comment: Not necessarilly, PHP 5.3 brought us the `goto` statement, which can jump after the return. [link](http://www.php.net/goto)

Comment: you are right. i suppose IDE, can handle with goto either.

Answer (score 0):

Using `return` in theses cases actually makes `break` redundant.  The break statement is there to stop fall-through of cases by jumping execution.  But since a return statement accomplishes that, too, the break becomes unnecessary.

A less flexible language with an opinionated and unclever compiler might complain, but the goal is achieved.  The code follows through the `switch` correctly, straight to the end of the function.